# Operating system for Personal & Enterprise application for Hadoop

Tags: open-source, linux-distribution, operating-system, hadoop

*I ain't sure if this is a right forum to ask this question. Please let me know which SE site I have to use, in case I am on the wrong forum.*

I have started learning Hadoop & I have tried Hortonworks on my system (using VmWare or VirtualBox). I don't want to work on distribution provided by any company reason:

- As I am expecting new projects from clients so I would need to install only required component on the server.
- I want to learn Hadoop more deeper.

Now, being from Windows background I am searching for a OS which is suitable for Hadoop (I just want to install Hive & Spark). Doing a limited knowledge search on Google I came to know that following OS are suitable for installing Apache Hadoop

- CentOS
- Linux Mint
- Fedora
- Ubuntu

I am looking for a OS which can run on my laptop (6 GB RAM) and also I can recommend to run on the Enterprise production server. 
Also, being a beginner & from MS background I want installation & maintenance to be hassle free. Which OS will do best for me because I will be using same OS to work on personal computer as well as for Enterprise production server.

Answer (score 1):

"Hassle free" in your question translates to which operating system has the best combination of official and community support, which in my opinion is clearly Ubuntu.

**Stack Overflow questions tagged with hadoop ranked by number of questions**

- Ubuntu - 1,645 results
- CentOS -     428 results
- Fedora -      36 results
- Linux Mint  - 27 results

Ubuntu dominates the search results at Stack Overflow and there are also 176 questions tagged with hadoop at Ask Ubuntu Q&A.

Ubuntu also has very good package management. I recommend installing the latest Long Term Support (LTS) release which is Ubuntu 16.04. Ubuntu 16.04 can be easily upgraded to the next LTS release, Ubuntu 18.04, when it is released in April, 2018. Security and maintenance updates are provided for Ubuntu LTS releases for five years after the release date.

Comment: Same could be said for Mint (which is based upon and Ubuntu and improves it). But admitted, the advantage of Ubuntu from the view of a Stack Exchange user is: it has *AskUbuntu,* while there's no explicit place for Mint – though there's always *Unix & Linux* :)

Comment: Appreciate your detailed response. +1. But does Ubuntu takes less RAM compared to CentOs, Fedora or Linux Mint?

Comment: This question requires a lengthy response because the RAM requirements of Ubuntu Server are quite frugal compared to Ubuntu desktop and also starting with Ubuntu 17.10 Ubuntu has changed the default desktop environment. This question on Ask Ubuntu puts all of the pieces together on the same page: [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar). Accepted answer has most of the essential information.

Comment: Comparing Ubuntu Server to CentOS, Mint Server or Fedora Server, they all require about the same amount of RAM. The default desktop editions also all require about the same amount of RAM.